# How to create the pre-receive hook on the GitHub Enterprise Server

Tags: git, github, github-enterprise

I am working on creating a pre-receive hook in the Github Enterprise Repository to do a check on the pushes. I tried renaming the `pre-receive.sample` to `pre-receive` in the `.git/hooks` folder and pushed it to the remote, but apparently this only works for the client-side hook, not server-side hook. I am the owner of this repo. I am following this [guide](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/admin/developer-workflow/creating-a-pre-receive-hook-script#writing-a-pre-receive-hook-script) and I don't understand what does it mean "**Create the pre-receive hook on the GitHub Enterprise Server instance**" Here is the setting of my project. How do I access the Github Enterprise Server? Thanks for any help! [image]

Comment: This needs to be done by a site admin. Details are on this page for adding them https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.18/admin/developer-workflow/managing-pre-receive-hooks-on-the-github-enterprise-server-appliance#creating-pre-receive-hooks

Comment: I am having a gray moment with this. How does it show repositories that contain hook scripts? 

I have tried crating some repos (both under as admin or one of the organizations) and some scripts - but it doesn't show up in the drop down of "Select hook repository"

Any help here would be amazing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Enterprise Site Administrators are responsible for managing pre-recieve hooks. Within the settings for GitHub Enterprise they will see a screen such as this for setting hooks:
[image]

Administering hooks is described here:
https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.18/admin/developer-workflow/managing-pre-receive-hooks-on-the-github-enterprise-server-appliance

Once a pre-recieve hook has been created by  your Site Administrators it will be available to be selected via the repo's Settings->Hooks screen.
[image]

I believe it is done this way to protect GitHub Enterprise from long running scripts which may cause performance issues.